# Expand bash variable within piped command

Tags: bash, pipe, function

This is the function that I'm using–or trying to use–to restore a database in a docker container:

`function restoredb()
{
    # source: see above
    local wkdir="pwd | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev"
    local container='echo ${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1'
    cat backup.sql | docker exec -i ${container} /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=dockerpass wordpress
}`

I would like the `docker exec` function to interpret `${container}` the same way it would if it were not piped:

`function dumpdb()
{
    # source https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042938/2223106
    # source https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb
    local wkdir="pwd | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev"
    local container='echo ${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1'
    docker exec ${container} mysqldump -uroot --password=password wordpress > backup.sql
}`

When I run the function as is, Docker `exec` is looking for a container called `echo`.

I imagine that maybe `eval` or `tee` would help, but I'm a bit in the dark.

Running commands after `set -x`

The output for non-working `restoredb` is:

`+ restoredb
+ local 'wkdir=pwd | rev | cut -d / -f1 | rev'
+ local 'container=echo ${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1'
+ cat backup.sql
+ docker exec -i echo '${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1' /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=dockerpass wordpress
Error response from daemon: No such container: echo
++ checkdir
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' -a -d env ']'`

For the working one, `dumpdb`:

`+ docker exec renaissance_my-wpdb_1 mysqldump -uroot --password=dockerpass wordpress
++ pwd
++ checkdir
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' -a -d env ']'`

Then for anyone as uninformed as me, `set +x` removes the verbose output.

Comment: The variable **is** being expanded. I don't know about the rest of the problem.

Comment: But without the pipe, Docker exec receives the _result_ of `'echo ${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1'` and here it seems to receive "echo...".

Comment: No, it doesn't. I don't know how the docker command works, I'm just telling you what Bash does.

Comment: Did you mean to use backticks instead of single quotes?

Comment: in assigning the `container` variable?

Comment: Yes. Though surely `container=${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1` would be the same thing in that case. Perhaps the real command is more complex.

Comment: Use `set -x` to compare the actual docker command lines.

Comment: @HaukeLaging that sounds promising. Where would that go in the function?

Comment: Are you sure that `dumpdb` works? I'm not sure what your expectations are, but I can't see how it does anything reasonable.

Comment: Yes. `dumpdb` works. It dumps the sql to the `working directory`. Updated the question to show output from `set -x` if that offers any insight.

Comment: The trace output from running dumpdb would be fascinating. Just `set -x` before you call the function.

Comment: Updated the questin with those outputs. Thanks for `set -x`. Cool.

Comment: The `dumpdb` output doesn't seem to correspond to the function you've posted, or you've left out some lines at the top. I don't know how you're running these, but if it's interactively then `type dumpdb` might be informative.

Comment: Hmmm. `type dumpdb` gives me `dumpdb is aliased to 'docker exec...', which it had been at one point. But I have re-sourced the `~/.bashrc` that had _formerly_ had that alias in it. I'm now sourcing the functions from a project-specific file.

Answer (score 3):

Reversing twice to obtain working directory is perverse. You just wanted this:

```
basename `pwd`
```

(Or `basename $PWD` if you prefer.)

Putting commands in a pipeline is not relevant to this question, as it seems to be all about quoting. If you really want to explore quoting details, you might compare `cat ReadMe | some_cmd | sort` with `cat ReadMe | bash -c 'some_cmd' | sort`.

When you write

```
local container='echo ${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1'
```

I don't understand what role you're hoping `echo` will play in this. Note that single-quote inhibits $ variable expansion. Don't you want simply this?

```
local container="${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1"
```

(You could even omit the quotes, there, as working directory has no spaces.)

Debug with `echo $container` or `set -x`, then execute as above: `... | docker exec -i ${container} /usr/bin/mysql ...`

Comment: Okay thank you. Surrounding `basename $PWD` with backticks seems to work. `local wkdir=basename $PWD` without the backticks did not.

Comment: @MikeiLL Or use `${PWD##*/}` like I showed you in my answer to your other question.

Comment: He may omit the quotes no matter whether the `$wkdir` has spaces or not as it doesn't matter in a simple assignment like that. See `a='hello world'; b=$a`.

Comment: @Kusalananda would you mind to explain how putting the `##*/` in the `PWD` variable reference gets only the final part of the path?

Comment: @MikeiLL `${parameter##word}` will remove the longest possible match of `word` from the start of `$parameter`. See the bash manual.

Comment: Wow. That is a sweet feature! So in this case `*/` is a regular expression specifying `any number of an character followed by a slash`